# Typhoon Swift Framework - How to inject parameters in initializers

Tags: swift, typhoon

With Swift I should be able to initialise a Service with its dependencies for example RepositoryA and RepositoryB

Let's say the Service should be transient and the repositories are singletons

All I could find was this:

https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Types-of-Injections#injection-with-run-time-arguments

But I'm missing a swift sample for the initialiser of the Service and for the container with initWithParameter using the initialiser that has several parameters

Any code available ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform an initializer injection with Typhoon, use the equivalent Swift code for the example shown in the user guide. It looks like this:

```
public dynamic func citiesListController() -> AnyObject {

    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(CitiesListViewController.self) {
        (definition) in

        definition.useInitializer("initWithCityDao:theme:") {
            (initializer) in

            initializer.injectParameterWith(self.coreComponents.cityDao())
            initializer.injectParameterWith(self.themeAssembly.currentTheme())
        }
    }

}
```

The [Typhoon Swift sample application](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon-Swift-Example), from which the above code was taken, shows further examples.

Comment: In CitiesListViewController the initialiser looks like this:

        
    init(cityDao : CityDao, theme : Theme) {
        super.init(nibName: "CitiesList", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        self.cityDao = cityDao
        self.theme = theme
    }

Whats the trick to know how to call the initialiser "initWithCityDaoTheme:theme:״ ?

Can someone clarify this syntax? Is it initWith + type1 parameter + type2 parameter always?

Comment: Yes, follow the order of the parameters - you're making an Objective-C selector from the Swift method.